# Continuing a conversation after manually calling the signin helper

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm a bit confused about how to handle the following scenario:

1. The user triggers the `FooBarIntent` whose fulfillment requires a linked account from a third party.
2. I manually call the [`signin helper`](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers#account_sign-in) from my fulfillment code.
3. The user authorizes my agent, Actions on Google sends the helpers response with the signin status to Dialogflow, where a `SignIn` intent picks it up and passes it to my fulfillment service.

Now how do I proceed with fulfilling the original `FooBarIntent`? I thought this would somehow be handled seamlessly, but the signin helpers response is an entirely new webhook request with no information about the original request. It seems that I could store that information in a context, but that seems rather clumsy. Am I missing something here, or do I really have to tell the user something like "thanks for logging in, now please ask your original question again"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying "Now please ask your original question again" is certainly the wrong approach to take - you have that part correct.

You're also correct that there is no automatic re-triggering of the original Intent. While this seems odd, it is simply because Intents represent what the user has said - not what you're going to be replying with. Both the user's initial statement and their sign-in acknowledgement are separate things that the user has said, and you may wish to handle each differently.

As you suggest - one thing that makes sense to do is to respond to the initial thing they said before you got the results from the helper. In these cases, saving the Intent or Action name and parameters in a context when you request the helper can let you pick back up afterwards. (There are other possible behaviors, however, that could make sense. Consider, for example, if you request sign-in as part of the welcoming intent. Since the user never gets past this first step, you don't need to keep track of the state.)

This pattern of saving the state when you take a detour to get the sign-in is one that is directly supported by the [multivocal](https://multivocal.info/) library, for example. With multivocal, you specify the requirements necessary before an Intent or Action handler is triggered (such as requiring the user to be authenticated). It takes care of meeting those requirements and then making sure the conversation continues where you left off to take the detour.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to make sure I didn't overlook something. Multivocal looks interesting, but since I'm on Python I guess I'll have to go with the context approach.

Comment: Multivocal just uses the context approach and handles it for the developer - it was just an example of a slightly different way to approach the problem as part of a library.